# Sharepoint REST API search on multiple sites

Tags: search, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Using the [Sharepoint REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search) with a query similar to `https://{tentant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/root/search(q='{text}')` I can only get results from a single site/drive at a time. There is no way to directly filter by file type, modification date or any other property either.

Using Sharepoint's inbuilt search function (`https://{tentant}.sharepoint.com/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=text`) however offers these features. Is there a way for a user to directly search for files on all available Sharepoint sites using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specificly searching for files I would recommend creating a tenant or web app level search result source and use that one in the rest query, setting "id= guid of that Search result source"

Comment: How would I query such a result source via REST on a Sharepoint 365 site? I am unable to find any documentation on this.

Comment: Use the SourceID property and the GUID of the Result Source.